# Circle div without resizing

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, geometry

I've created a circle div with this line of code:

```
style="width: 25%; height: auto; padding-top: 25%; margin-left: 37.5%; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #00e5c9; overflow: hidden; bottom: 0;">
```

However, when I add an image inside of it, it expands and thus becomes an oval. Is there a way to keep the circle as it is with no uneven expansion? I would like to add that determining the width and height with pixels is out of the picture since I'm trying to create a responsive page.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not set the height to a fixed percentage too?

Comment: @JordanS the div doesn't actually appear when I give it a height percentage.

Comment: You've asked 10 questions but accepted the answers to none of them. Please take a moment to go back and review the answers given on your previous questions. Accepting answers helps those that take the time to provide help, future visitors, and you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position:absolute` on the `img`.

Example

```
 img{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%)

}
```

Snippet below

```css
#d {
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 25%;
  margin-left: 37.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #00e5c9;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
}

#d img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  ;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div id="d">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzQljZiYwAlULvViQAWNnBaIz4r_61X09p2lcgZCTVrEBN4Rot"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify for me why you used 'transform'? And also why you changed the dimension sizes for the image twice?

Comment: It is a css3 property when  position the image 50% downwards (top:50%). THe top of the image is at the 50% mark . That is the middle of the image is not position at the 50% from the parent container. Hence you use transform to just translate the image 50% (half way) from its original position

Comment: If you google css transform you will find alot of info to understand the various functionality

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you again!